# Finding the sum of unknown elements of a set given certain conditions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, permutations, combinations

Let A={$1,a_1,a_2,...,a_{18},77$} be a set of integers with $$1\lt a_1\lt a_2....\lt a_{18}\lt77.$$Let the set A+A={$x+y:x,y\in A$} contain exactly 39 elements. Then the value of $a_1+a_2+a_3+..+a_{18}$?

In this, i can clearly see that 36 elements would be of the type $a_1+1,a_2+1....,a_{18}+1$ and $a_1+77, a_2+77, a_3+77...,a_{18}+77$ But I don't understand how to proceed from here and which pairs I can consider to be common? Or am I interpreting the problem in a completely wrong manner?
Thank You.

Comment: @nonuser a18<77

Comment: @nonuser kindly clarify what do you wish to ask?

Comment: I think the smallest $|A+A|$ could be is 37 elements, when $A$ is the arithmetic sequence $A = \{1, 5, 9, \ldots, 73, 77\}$, $A+A = \{6, 10, 14, \ldots, 146, 150\}$. So probably if $|A+A| = 39$, the situation is a slight modification of that?

Comment: @aschepler $x$ and $y$ are not required to be distinct.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Oops, right. So, then...

Comment: @nonuser Extremely sorry, I hope there are no more editing errors this time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $A$ has $20$ elements ordered as
$$
\color{blue}{a_0:=1}<a_1<a_2<\dots<a_{18}<\color{red}{77=:a_{19}}\ .
$$
Here is a list of
$39=
\color{blue}{1}+18+
\color{orange}{1}+18+
\color{red}{1}$ elements in $A+A$, ordered in a "chain" $\Gamma$ based on the above as
$$\tag{$\Gamma$}$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Gamma\ :\qquad
\color{blue}{1+1} &< 1+a_1 < 1+a_2 < \dots < 1+a_{18} 
\\
&< \color{orange}{1+77}
\\
&< 77+a_1  < 77+a_2 < \dots < 77+ a_{18} 
< \color{red}{77 + 77}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So these are the elements of $A+A$. Well, let's try to see if such a situation can be arranged. Now let us take a look at the following "chains" of numbers, considered as ordered lists, i am typing them explicitly:
$$
\begin{aligned}
C(1)  \ :& &&  1+1 <   1+a_1 <   1+a_2 < \dots <   1+a_{18} <   1+77\ , \\
C(a_1)\ :& &&a_1+1 < a_1+a_1 < a_1+a_2 < \dots < a_1+a_{18} < a_1+77\ , \\
C(a_2)\ :& &&a_2+1 < a_2+a_1 < a_2+a_2 < \dots < a_2+a_{18} < a_2+77\ , \\
\vdots& &&\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad
\\
C(a_{18})\ :& &&a_{18}+1 < a_{18}+a_1 < a_{18}+a_2 < \dots < a_{18}+a_{18} < a_{18}+77\ , \\
C(77)\ :& &&77+1 < 77+a_1 < 77+a_2 < \dots < 77+a_{18} < 77+77\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Each such "chain" is included in the chain $\Gamma$. Let us see how.
The first chain $C(1)$ takes the first $20$ elements in $\Gamma$, so the elements
in positions $1$ to $20$ in the ordered set $\Gamma$, which as a set only is $A+A$.

The chain $C(a_1)$ takes some elements from $\Gamma$, but can it be that we "skip" some entry? It is clear that it starts in position $2$, which is $a_1+1$,
it ends in position $21$ or strictly higher, but can it really be strictly higher?
No, because $C(a_1)$ would end in a position $\ge 22=21+1$, $C(a_2)$ would end then in a position strictly higher than that of $C(a_1)$, so at least $23=21+2$,  $C(a_3)$ would end in a position strictly higher than that of $C(a_2)$, so at least $24=21+3$, and so on, $C(a_{18})$ would end in position at least $21+18=39$, and then $C(77)$... well, there is no position left. Contradiction.

So $C(a_1)$ matches exactly the positions $2$ to $21$.
With the same argument, $C(a_2)$ takes the positions $3$ to $22$, and so on.
Finally, $C(a_{18})$ takes the positions $19$ to $38$, and
$C(77)$ takes the last positions, $20$ to $39$.
(Finite induction based on the same story.)

Putting the chains $C(1)$, $C(a_1)$, $C(a_2)$ over each other so that same
numbers are in the same column we have the parallel structure
$$
\begin{matrix}
C(1)  \ :1+1 &<1+a_1 &<  1+a_2 &<   1+a_3 &<   1+a_4 &<   1+a_5 &<  1+a_6 &< \dots\ , \\
C(a_1)\ :    & a_1+1 &<a_1+a_1 &< a_1+a_2 &< a_1+a_3 &< a_1+a_4 &< a_1+a_5&< \dots\ , \\
C(a_2)\ :    &       & a_2+1 &<a_2+a_1 &< a_2+a_2 &< a_2+a_3 &< a_2+a_4 &<  \dots\ , \\
\end{matrix}
$$
and so on. From here we get step by step
$a_2=2a_1-1$
, $a_3=a_1+a_2-1=3a_1-2$,
, $a_4=a_1+a_3-1=4a_1-3$,
and so on.

So $A$ is an arithmetic progression starting with $1$, having increment $a_1-1$,
and so that $a_{19}=19a_1-18=77$, so $a_1=5$:
$$
A=(1<5<9<\dots<73<77)\ .
$$
It remains to add the elements from $5$ to $73$ from the list...